# How can I force a PowerShell runbook return English error messages

Tags: pnp-powershell, localization

I have a localized tenant and troubleshooting a SharePoint provisioning runbook.
My problem is that it returns mixed (localized and English) error messages.
Like `New-PnPWeb` gives English errors, but `Apply-PnPProvisioningTemplate` returns with Hungarian.
I tried adding this to the script, didn't help:

```
[Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = 'en-US'
```

Can somebody give me a hint?

Answer (score 0):

With PnP I had this problem as well, I always got German error messages which you just cannot Google well.

I got it to English by switching the language for the user I used to authenticate with PnP. Once I set everything to English for this user (Account, My Site) the error message switched to English immediately. This of course will only apply when authenticating as user.